# why automatic OTP verification is not working for Redmi note 5 pro mobile

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase phone authentication for `otp` verification. `onVerifactionCompleted` method is not invoked so, automatic fetch is not happened in my app.

But , Manually I can enter received `otp`.

Please help me to find out the solution for this problem.

```
private void sendVerificationCode(final String phonenumber) {
    Log.d("getsms", "phoneNumber " + phonenumber);
    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            phonenumber,
            60,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            OtpActivity.this,
            new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
                    Log.d("getsms", "code " + phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode());
                    mobileotp = phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode();
                    Otptxt.setText(mobileotp );
                    verifyCode(mobileotp);


                }

                @Override
                public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {
                    Log.d("getsms","fail "+e.getMessage());

                }

                @Override
                public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String s, @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                    super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
                    verificationid = s;
                    Log.d("getsms","verificationid "+verificationid);
                }
            }
    );
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add more details + relevant code sections.

Comment: Please tell us more... What method are you using to detect OTP ... Please Update your question....For more info please read [how-to-ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I added my code with this question. Please, verify that im struggling on this problem @PraveenSP